# System Modeler can't find g++ in Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: ccompilerdriver, system-modeler

I've just purchased SystemModeler (Mac OS X Mavericks) but can't verify the g++ compiler path. I assume it's in the Xcode package but nothing I've tried seems to work, for example,

Applications/xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin

Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, it's actually not in XCode by default. You'll have to install "command line tools" for mac from `XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > Command Line Tools > Install`. If you upgrade to XCode 5, it should come with the command line tools.

Comment: I have Xcode 5.0.1 but command line tools are missing from components. I tried /usr/bin/xcode-select --install but command line tools couldn't be found.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: [How can I install the Command Line Tools completely from the command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107307)

Comment: System Modeler instructions only state that Xcode must be installed so I thought that's where the compiler would be. After finding use/bin I see that the g++ executable is in that directory. However, System Modeler>Preferences>Global>Compiler fails to validate that path.

Comment: Tried your suggested command line tool install but Mavericks blocked it. "Valid only for Mountain Lion."

Comment: @nilglew Can you execute `g++` or `gcc` from the command line (Terminal)?

Comment: Can you not set the path for where System Modeler searches for the executables?

Comment: The easiest way is to install SystemModeler 4. For a workaround for SystemModeler 3, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was formally informed by WRI personnel that the system modeler is not (yet) compatible with 10.9

Comment: Information from @yehuda about another example of Apple fooling a vendor probably answers my question. (MS mostly fools users.) It was a case of bad timing on my part; should have waited a descent interval to get System Modeler after 10.9. Thanks everyone for the assistance; beyond some javascript I don't do code, which is why I use higher-end tools like Mathematica, but I enjoy reading the command line talk. You guys are awesome.

Comment: See my answer for a way to run SystemModeler on 10.9

Comment: It is directly compatible with 10.9 now, with version 4.0

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this problem, which is in fact resulted from the missing of gcc and apple developer tool.
1.gcc:
refer to this page for the installation of gcc 4.8:
[gcc 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9](http://hpc.sourceforge.net)

2.Apple Developer Tool:
Just install it by executing this command in Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After install the developer tool, verify the g++ compiler in Preferences of SystemModeler under the compiler section.
Good luck.

Comment: I can invoke the compiler from the command line ... "which g++" says `/usr/bin`, putting `/usr/bin` in the compiler section of the preferences results in "Compiler verification failed. Change the settings and try again."

Answer (score 2):

### SystemModeler 4

SystemModeler 4 supports Mac OS X Mavericks out of the box.

### SystemModeler 3

Locate the Compile script in the SystemModeler bundle, in a standard installation it should be located here `/Applications/SystemModeler.app/Contents/MacOS/Compile`.

To get there, right-click (or Ctrl+left click) on the SystemModeler bundle and select "Show Package Contents". Then you can browse into Contents/MacOS. Open the Compile file in a text editor and substitute the contents with this:

`#!/bin/sh
export export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8
make $2 -f $1.makefile > $1.log 2>&1`

Warning: Make sure that the new file does NOT use windows line endings, because then nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

> xcode-select --install

Could be not work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools/9964905#9964905). But it is posible to download from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action, it is required to sign in (or sign up if you don't have a apple account).

After that, like sunt05 suggest (sorry, I can't vote), you must install gcc 4.8 binaries following the instructions of hpc.sourceforge.net. Then, in system modeler put the path /usr/local/bin and push verify.